# Change 31-Jul-03 style to Date Object of mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I am using python 3.5

I have query like `31-Jul-03`.

Now I would like to change this to `2003-07-31` or something available for mysql Date object.

Of course I can parse this query step by step, but, it is a bit trouble some and Some have the same problem as well.

Is there any good library or idea to handle this Date object??

Comment: python datetime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the datetime module is what you're looking for. It can be used as such to solve your problem:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('31-Jul-03', '%d-%b-%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2003-07-31'
```

Source: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm

Comment: Thanks strptime gives me the perfect solution!!

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you could use to convert string to DATE type:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('31-Jul-03','%d-%b-%y');
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/YOH82878)**

Comment: Thanks this is also the usuful answer though, I need to change this in python.